# Why is the copy constructor called instead of the move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

Consider the following code:

```
class Outer
{   
class Inner
{
public:
    Inner(Inner&& i):outers(std::move(i.outers)),test(std::move(test))
    {}

    void addOuter(const Outer& o) {outers.push_back(std::move(o));} 
private:
    std::vector<Outer> outers;      
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> test;      
};

public:
Outer(Outer&& o):inners(std::move(o.inners))
{}
private:
std::vector<Inner> inners;

};
```

When I try to compile the code above on Visual Studio 2012, I get the following error:

`Error  1   error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'`

Apparently the compiler invokes the copy constructor instead of the move constructor in the push_back found in the `addOuter` method. Is this a compiler bug? If not why, for this specific case, isn't the move constructor called?

Comment: Possibly because `o` is passed as a `const` reference to `addOuter`.

Comment: @Andrey That should be an answer.

Comment: It looks like you need an `void addOuter(Outer&& o) {outers.push_back(std::move(o));} ` overload

Comment: BTW, that is some terribly formatted code...

Comment: Your move constructor should initialise `test` from `i.test`, not from itself.

Answer (score 13):

Because `o` is passed as a `const` reference to `addOuter`.

Comment: @register no, this is right. The const reference makes `std::move` yield an lvalue reference. Removing the `const` would result in the move yielding a nameless rvalue.

Comment: I cannot upvote until the answer is edited again. Please do so and I will remove my downvote.